# angular.js con el módulo angular-chartist

Tags: angularjs

Estoy tratando de enlazar chartis.js con angular.js he buscado en la documentación pero está bastante desactualizada, me gustaría un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo.

Este es mi código:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Angular Chartist</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css">
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js">      </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <script src="angular-chartist.js"></script>
    </head>

   <body ng-app="app">
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <section class="container-fluid" ng-controller="ChartistExampleCtrl as Chartist ">
   <h1>Chart Examples</h1>
   <div class="row">
   <chartist class="ct-chart" chartist-data="chartist.data" chartist-chart-type="Bar"></chartist>
   </div>
   </section>
   <script src="index.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Este es mi código javascript index.js:

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['angular-chartist']);

 app.controller('ChartistExampleCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.data = {
    labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'],
    series: [
      [1000, 1200, 1300, 1200, 1440, 1800],
      [1600, 1550, 1497, 1440, 1200, 1000],
    ]
    }

   }
 ]);
```

Y finalmente mi código css (app.css):

```
  .ct-chart .ct-label {
   font-size: 1.4rem;
  }
```

No se qué estaré haciendo mal, pero no logro hacer que funcione.

Comment: Hola @Uchicha Sasuke. Bienvenido a SOes. Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: ya agrege lo que has sugerido

Comment: @devconcept espero que la informacion que he agregado sea suficiente